# replace word characters with another - regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to replace a word characters with other 'any' special characters, like in this example:

```
"if there is a definitive answer ? $120.223"
to
"** ***** ** * ********* ****** * ****.***"
```

or by maintain the first and the last character of each word, as:

```
"if there is a definitive answer ? $120.223"
to
"if t***e is a d*******e a****r ? $***.**3"
```

Could that be achieved using regex instead of build a pure-code (manually) function?

I think it could be achieve using sub function in re python library, but I don't have an idea to what use in the second parameter of the function (repl) !? if so, any proposed resource?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex to select the middle of non-whitespace sequences

```
([^\s])([^\s]*)([^\s])
```

then replace the middle part (\2) with the proper number of * characters. If you want to skip the . character you'll have to do that separately

Comment: what is the (\2) ? , also I want to replace each character with a new special character not to a specific number of characters?

Comment: \2 is the second group of the results ( in this case: ([^\s]*) ). It's the part you want to replace

Comment: could you pass a reference to know how to control that in the second parameter, what is the proper way! if I put \1*\3, it will be replace by just one asterisk !

Comment: I'm afraid it can not be done without coding, regex replace has no length information

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
s="if there is a definitive answer ? $120.223"
print(s)
print(re.sub("[a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]", '*', s))
```

output

```
if there is a definitive answer ? $120.223
** ***** ** * ********** ****** ? $***.***
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, since there is no function to know the length of middle characters as @Lance_Toth said in his comment, I worked on the "character level" in regex:

```
reg = r'((?<!\b)[^\s0-9](?=[a-zA-Z$]))'
txt = 'There seem to be an , fdf'

print(re.sub(reg, r'*', txt))
```

output:

```
T***e s**m to be an , f*f
```